# GtkProgressBar with CSS for progress colour not functioning

Tags: c, gtk

I am not able to change the colour of the progress element in the GtkProgressBar using CSS. I have tried different combinations to reference this progress bar such as the below but to no avail. I have attached a minimum example C program, Glade file and CSS file where CSS attempt 4 is currently active to demonstrate that all elements are affected except this progress bar.

```
/* attempt 1 */
#gtkprogressbar1 {
    color: rgba(83,165,198,255);
    background-color: rgba(83,165,198,255);
}
/* attempt 2 */
#progressbar * {
    color: rgba(83,165,198,255);
    background-color: rgba(83,165,198,255);
}
/* attempt 3 */
GtkProgressBar * {
    color: rgba(83,165,198,255);
    background-color: rgba(83,165,198,255);
}
/* attempt 4 */
* {
    color: rgba(83,165,198,255);
    background-color: rgba(83,165,198,255);
}
```

C Program: Save as progressbar.c

```
/* Compile as follows: 
* gcc -o PROGRESS progressbar.c -g `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 gmodule-2.0` -pthread `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 gmodule-2.0` -export-dynamic
*/
#include <gio/gio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    GtkWidget *button_on;
    GtkWidget *progressbar1;
    time_t time_start;
    time_t time_finish;
} app_gui;

void set_progress_bar (app_gui *gui);

void adding_timer (app_gui *gui);

void set_css (void);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    GtkBuilder *builder = g_slice_new (GtkBuilder);
    GtkWidget *window;
    GError *gtk_error = NULL;

    app_gui *gui = g_slice_new (app_gui);

    gui->time_start = time (NULL);
    gui->time_finish = gui->time_start + 60; // 60 seconds progress bar
    printf("%s%lu\n", "button click: Time start at button click is ", gui->time_start);
    printf("%s%lu\n", "button click: Time finish at button click is ", gui->time_finish);

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    set_css ();

    builder = gtk_builder_new ();
    if (!gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "progressbar_main.glade", NULL)) {
        fprintf (stdout, "%s%s\n", "Error loading file with the reason: ", gtk_error->message);
        g_free (gtk_error);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    window = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window_main"));
    gui->button_on = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "button_on"));
    gui->progressbar1 = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "progressbar1"));

    gtk_builder_connect_signals (builder, gui);

    g_object_unref (builder);

    g_timeout_add_seconds_full (G_PRIORITY_DEFAULT_IDLE, 1, (GSourceFunc)set_progress_bar, 
        gui, (GDestroyNotify)adding_timer);

    gtk_widget_show (window);
    gtk_main ();

    g_slice_free (app_gui, gui);
    return 0;

}

void set_css (void) {

    GtkCssProvider *css_provider;
    GdkDisplay *display;
    GdkScreen *screen;
    const char *css_file = "style.css";
    GError *error = NULL;

    css_provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
    display = gdk_display_get_default ();
    screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen (display);
    gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen (screen, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (css_provider), 
        GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);


    gtk_css_provider_load_from_file(css_provider, g_file_new_for_path (css_file), &error);
    g_object_unref (css_provider);  
}

void adding_timer (app_gui *gui) {

    g_timeout_add_seconds_full (G_PRIORITY_DEFAULT_IDLE, 1, (GSourceFunc)set_progress_bar, 
    gui, (GDestroyNotify)adding_timer);

}

void set_progress_bar (app_gui *gui) {

    time_t time_now = time (NULL);

    double progress = 1.00 - (((gui->time_finish * 1.0) - time_now)/60.0);

    printf("%s%f\n", "set progress: Progress is ", progress);
    if (progress >= 1.00) {
        EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    gtk_progress_bar_set_fraction (GTK_PROGRESS_BAR (gui->progressbar1), progress); 

}

void on_window_main_destroy () {

    gtk_main_quit ();
}
```

Glade File: Save as progressbar_main.glade

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.18.3 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.12"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window_main">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window_main_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkFixed" id="fixed1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button_on">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">ON</property>
            <property name="width_request">100</property>
            <property name="height_request">80</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">48</property>
            <property name="y">75</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkViewport" id="viewport1">
            <property name="width_request">200</property>
            <property name="height_request">80</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkTextView" id="textview1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">201</property>
            <property name="y">75</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkProgressBar" id="progressbar1">
            <property name="width_request">200</property>
            <property name="height_request">-1</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">53</property>
            <property name="y">31</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

CSS File: Save as style.css

```
* {
    color: rgba(83,165,198,255);
    background-color: rgba(83,165,198,255);
}
```

Thank you for any assistance offered.

Comment: why not call `set_css()` after UI is initializing from glade file.

Comment: Placing set_css() anywhere between gtk_init() and gtk_main() does not change the colour including before and after the initialisation of the glade file.

Answer (score 1):

All of your attempts to select the ProgressBar widget are wrong:

- In your UI file, `progressbar1` is the `id`, not the `name`, and it's Glade's `name` that gets used as the CSS ID. Confusing, right? Anyway, it's not `gtkprogressbar1`, so that wouldn't work regardless.
- An ID like `#widgetclass`, e.g. `#progressbar`, is never used by GTK+ as the CSS ID is per-element, not per-class, and only one widget per process should have the same CSS name, but all GtkProgressBars would in this hypothetical.
- `GtkProgressBar` style names are the old style, pre 3.18ish, and I presume you're not using so old a version (but you can try substituting it if you are).

The CSS node name, as of now, is `progressbar`, not `GtkProgressBar`. The same pattern applies to other widgets: all nodes named `GtkWhatever` are now named `whatever` generally, with a few minor exceptions (e.g. `GtkListBox` is `list`).

So that's one problem. Your second is that your attempts to change the colour are not using specific enough selectors and therefore are being overridden by whatever theme you're using applying more specific selectors than `*` - which is to say: all of them.

Even if your colour would take effect this way, it would have to apply to the whole widget, which is obviously wrong.

[Read the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkProgressBar.html#GtkProgressBar.description) to learn the proper CSS node names and hierarchies, and select on something more specific, e.g.:

```
progressbar > trough > progress
```

is the most specific variant.

That said, if you prefer brevity, I just ran `gtk3-widget-factory` and found this to be sufficient to style the `progress` fill node:

```
progressbar progress {
    background-color: rgba(83, 165, 198, 255);
}
```

So, yes: just selecting on `progressbar` alone produces wrong results because you're not being specific enough. That's why we need separate CSS nodes and why the node hierarchy is documented!

Comment: Interesting. Is there a way to also set the width/height of the current indicator? I have this problem that the progress bar indicator is super thin. I saw other screenshots where the bar is very thick so I wonder how to do this via CSS.

Comment: @shevy try `min-(width|height)` properties on the `trough` node